# ValueError in classifier.predict

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I get this error and I don't know what it means.
I read here in stackoverflow that the problem could be due to a dataset that has less than 1960 rows but I deliberately put a dataset with 2000 rows.
And that's not the problem.
Anyone know what she derives from?
Thanks .

```
from sklearn import *
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import tree

training_data = np.genfromtxt('output.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.int32, usecols=np.arange(0,11))

inputs = training_data[:,:-1]
outputs = training_data[:, -1]

training_inputs = inputs[:250]
training_outputs = outputs[:250] 
testing_inputs = inputs[250:]
testing_outputs = outputs[250:]

classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier.fit(training_inputs, training_outputs)

predictions = classifier.predict(testing_inputs) #error


ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 10)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 10)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

As the error explains, the provided numpy array does not have any values.

`shape=(0, 10)` refers to numpy array of 0 rows with 10 columns.

After loading the file, kindly print the size of input & output.